# UnsatisfiedDependencyException with REST service

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

I am trying to create some unit tests for my REST API service class. This service class implements a service interface. However, when I try to run my tests I get this error:

> org.springFramework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dev.x.y.unit.ContactServiceImplTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'contactServiceImpl';

My test class:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class ContactServiceImplTest {

@MockBean
private ContactRepository contactRepository;

@Autowired
private ContactServiceImpl contactServiceImpl;
...
```

my contactServiceImpl implements from my ContactService, I have tried annotating with @Component and @Service, but I am still receiving the same error.

ContactServiceImpl class:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ContactServiceImpl implements ContactService {

Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContactServiceImpl.class);

@Autowired
private final ContactRepository contactRepository;
....
```

My interface:

```
@Service
public interface ContactService { ... }
```

Any advice would be amazing.

Comment: are you trying to do integration test ? i believe you should use `@SpringBootTest`

Comment: In class ContactServiceImplTest try to change `@Autowired` for `@InjectMocks` and `@MockBean` for `@Mock`. You could try to use `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` instead of `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`.

Comment: @Deadpool the '@SpringBootTest' seems to have worked!